# Method [persistent] does not exist

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3

I am using `laravel auth` controller for user login.
I am getting "Method [persistent] does not exist" everytime i logged in.
I am using `laravel 5.3` for this.

```
in `AlertsMessageBag.php` line 153

at AlertsMessageBag->__call('persistent', array('ok')) in MainAccessControl.php line 22
at AlertsMessageBag->persistent('ok') in MainAccessControl.php line 22
at MainAccessControl->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 137
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 33
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in SubstituteBindings.php line 41
at SubstituteBindings->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 137
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 33
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 65
at VerifyCsrfToken->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 137
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 33
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in ShareErrorsFromSession.php line 49
at ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 137
```

Comment: What is `MainAccessControl` class?

Comment: I figure out.. Thank for you observation.. there was a persistent method called with alert info.